# mysql 8 default time zone for Switzerland, fix value for winter and summer

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> show variables where variable_name like '%zone%';
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| system_time_zone | CEST   |
| time_zone        | SYSTEM |
+------------------+--------+
```

My JDBC driver still complains with:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'CEST' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

The server and client is in Switzerland.

What is the problem with using CEST (Central European Summer Time)?

Do I need to set UTC+1? Or GMT+1?

And do I need to change this parameter on Summer and on Winter (UTC+2, GMT+2)???

Is there a way to define the default_time_zone with a value that I do not need to change between winter and summer?

Or can't it just take the time and time zone from the operating system?

Comment: So.. what are you trying to do? Apply offsets to date/time values pulled out of MySQL?

Comment: I want to configure mysql properly so that the JDBC driver stops complaining. The computer and client are in Switzerlnd.

Comment: I see, it's the driver that can't understand what MySQL is telling it. Sorry for butting in, I'm not a Java guy, have an upvote so others see it.